# Want to get corresponding contactid equivalent userid when querying from case

Tags: soql

Want to get corresesponding contactId's userId .

```
String userId = UserInfo.getUserID();

Select Id FROM Case Where Status NOT in (\'Closed\',\'Asta Closed\') AND **ContactId**=:userId order by CreatedDate desc  limit 1000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ContactId` is a field in the User object ([see documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_user.htm)).

You need to retrieve the user record and then you can use the field in the soql statement:

```
String userId = UserInfo.getUserId();
User u = [SELECT ContactId FROM User WHERE Id = :userId];
List<Case> cases = [SELECT Id FROM Case WHERE ContactId = :u.ContactId];
```